# Passing blade layout to phpword

Tags: php, html, xml, laravel, phpword

I'm using Laravel with phpword. So here i want to export html layout from blade file to word.
But when i trying to create it, the error that appearing : 
`DOMDocument::loadXML(): Opening and ending tag mismatch: link line 1 and head in Entity, line: 1`

My code:

```
$content = view('docs.index')->render();

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($content);
$dom->saveHTML();

$phpWord = new PhpWord();
Html::addHtml($phpWord->addSection(), $dom->saveHTML(), true);
$objWriter = IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'Word2007');
$objWriter->save('doc_index_'.Carbon::now()->format('d-m-y h-i').'.docx');

return view('papers.show')->with('success');
```

Here is my blade file :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Doc HTML</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <p>
        Laravel is a web application framework with expressive, elegant syntax. <br />
        We believe development must be an enjoyable and creative experience to be truly fulfilling. <br />
        Laravel takes the pain out of development by easing common tasks used in many web projects. <br />
    </p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Printing my $content variable :

```
"""
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Doc HTML</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <p>
        Laravel is a web application framework with expressive, elegant syntax. <br />
        We believe development must be an enjoyable and creative experience to be truly fulfilling. <br />
        Laravel takes the pain out of development by easing common tasks used in many web projects. <br />
    </p>
</div>
</body>
</html>

"""
```

Comment: It looks like there is an error in the markup somewhere in your blade file.

Comment: @jfadich i edited my question with adding blade file

Comment: can you echo $content  ?

Comment: @AhmedAboud yes, you can see it now

Comment: https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/issues/1515 follow this example

Comment: @AhmedAboud thank you, that link somehow helped me. Do you know, how to read `<style></style>` css parameters in PHPWord?

Comment: https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/blob/b1903524b99401e5d44829ef7dd860b16653bf83/src/PhpWord/Shared/Html.php#L54 check the function i think some way you will pass them in the options parameter

Answer (score 1):

I was facing exact same issue and got fixed with below work arou

```
$phpWord = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();
$section = $phpWord->addSection();

header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-word");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;Filename=".rand().".doc"); 
header("Pragma: no-cache"); header("Expires: 0");
```

and then simply render your view.
E.g return view('view_name');

Comment: I don't even know why PHP library is needed. With your solution by adding those headers and returning a blade view just downloads the doc file.

Answer (score 0):

Your `<meta>` tag is technically not closed. To follow the spec for elements that ommit a closing tag, they must be suffixed with `/>`. So just how you have `<br />` and `<link ... />` your meta tags should be `<meta ... />`.

Comment: I did it also, error is still shown this : `DOMDocument::loadXML(): Opening and ending tag mismatch: link line 1 and head in Entity, line: 1`

Answer (score 0):

The `<!DOCTYPE html>` part in the beginning of your template is causing that error. Regarding reading the style files, from the link to the function details provided there above in discussion [PHPWord/Html.php](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/blob/b1903524b99401e5d44829ef7dd860b16653bf83/src/PhpWord/Shared/Html.php#L54) you can see that addHtml will just use the contents of the body tag and ignore everything else.

Regarding the other question in the above discussion, I don't think that PHPWord supports any kind of style inclusion from css files - in this particular example, I'm not sure what would be the expected result in applying bootstrap responsive styling to word document content.